A cauchy sequence of $L^1$ functions always can exchange the limit and integration
Let $f_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ under the $L^1$-norm. If $f(x)$ is a (almost all) limit function for a subsequence $f_{n_k}$. Then I show that $f_n \to f$ in the $L^1$-norm use the following proof. My question is that is there more direct proof.
Proof:
First, write $g_k=f_{n_k}$, so $g_k(x)\to f(x)$ for almost all $x$. Since $f_n$ is Cauchy, it is enough to show that $g_k \to f$ in $L^1$-norm.Since $g_k$ is also Cauchy in $L^1$, $g_k$ has a subsequence $g_{k_j}$ so that $|g_{k_j}-g_{k_{j+1}}|_{L^1} <1/2^j$.
Let $H(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty  |g_{k_j}(x)-g_{k_{j+1}}(x)|$, and we can write the function as $f(x) =  \sum_{j=1}^\infty  g_{k_j}(x)-g_{k_{j+1}}(x)$.
Then the dominated convergence theorem implies that $|f-g_k|_{L^1} \to 0$ when $k\to \infty$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

@Anne Bauval. Thank you very much. I check this proof and I find no doubt in all steps. So I only retain the question "Is there more direct proof".

I don’t think there is a more direct proof. The trick of using the rapidly converging (or I should say rapidly Cauchy…?) subsequence and the dominated convergence theorem is the same thing one generally uses to prove that $L^1$ is complete, which looks roughly like what you are trying to prove.
